# How to configure Tomcat for request.getHeader("remote_user")?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I would like information on request.getHeader("remote_user") that is within my code.  I'm a entry level java/jsp developer and currently when my program calls for the value of this request, it returns null.  It should capture the user's credentials.  I haven't found any definitive information on the web or in textbooks regarding this request.  Is this something that I configure in Tomcat, in my browser or in my code?  Unfortunately, I can't post the code but when I'm finish with my code, I send it to an SA that post it on to Tomcat and request.getHeader("remote_user") does return the proper value.  But when I run it in my test configuration, on my Tomcat, request.getHeader("remote_user") returns null.  This leads me to believe that this is Tomcat.  Any information or education you can provide is appreciated, thank you.  SOrry for being able to post code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()`.

The `remote_user` header is just a mechanism between e.g. Apache HTTPD and Tomcat, and if you don't have an Apache HTTPD in your test setup, or it isn't configured the same as the production environment, you won't get it.

Comment: I am using HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser().  It's the Apache HTTPD, the SA that I send my code to load on Tomcat verified this.  He told me, if I don't have Apache HTTPD (and I don't), it won't work.  Thanks.